# I'm in trouble because locked connections are left behind by using spring's transactionmanager

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data, database-connection

I'm in trouble because locked connections remain by using Spring's Transactionmanager.

I am using the following items.

- Oracle 11g
- spring 1.4

example

- spring-boot
- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
- spring-security
- spring-webmvc

The application is running with spring boot tomcat

I manage the DB transaction of the application I am using Spring's TransactionManager.
If I operate from the screen for tens of minutes, the following sessions will remain.

[Execution query]

```
SELECT SELECT SID,STATUS,USERNAME,PROGRAM,state,wait_class,event,blocking_session_status,p1text,p2text FROM V$SESSION WHERE username = 'AAAA' and SID = ANY(SELECT SID FROM V$LOCK WHERE TYPE IN ('TX','TM'));
```

[Execution result]

```
138 INACTIVE    AAAA    JDBC Thin Client    WAITING Idle    SQL*Net message from client NO HOLDER   driver id   #bytes
```

This connection disappears when you stop tomcat.
I understand that I have an inactive session and that Tx or Tm locks remain.

Why can you predict if such an event will occur?
Thank you.

```html
[application.yml]

spring:
datasource:
driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
url: jdbc:oracle:thin:AAAA/AAAA@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1521:BBB

[XXXConfig.java]
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class XXXConfig {
 @Autowired
 private DataSourceProperties properties;
 private DataSource dataSource;
 @Bean
 private static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer()    {
  PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pspc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  pspc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
  return pspc;
 }
 @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
 @Bean
 DataSource dataSource() {
  DataSourceBuilder dsb = DataSourceBuilder
  .create(this.properties.getClassLoader())
  .url(this.properties.getUrl())
  .username(this.properties.getUsername())
  .password(this.properties.getPassword());
  this.dataSource = dsb.build();
  return this.dataSource;
 }
}

[TransactionAsct.java]
@Component
@Aspect
public class TransactionAspect {
private static final String POINTCUT_EXPRESSION = "@within(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController)";
 @Bean
 private TransactionHandler getTransactionHandler() {
 @Autowired
 private TransactionHandler th;
 @Bean
 private TransactionHandler getTransactionHandler() {
  return new TransactionHndlerImpl();
}
 @Around(POINTCUT_EXPRESSION)
 public Object around(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
 return th.invoke(new TransactionHandler.Func() {
  @Override
  public Object invoke() throws Throwable {
   return pjp.proceed();
  }
 });
}

[TransactionHandlerImpl.java]
@Component
public class TransactionHandlerImpl implements TransactionHandler {
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
@Override
public Object invoke(Func delegate) throws Throwable {
 return delegate.invoke();
}
```

Comment: It's impassible to say for sure without seeing the code that's executing that query and its transaction management. Can you add some more detail to your question?

Comment: I'm sorry.It is currently investigating where it is occurring.Therefore, it is difficult to show the relevant query.
Please do not say it reliably, so please let me know if there is any doubt.
Or in the past, please tell me if there are similar events.

Comment: Show your configuration. Also that connection will be there because you are (hopefully) using a connection pool which opens connections and reuses them.

Comment: I added a place that seems to be related.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why do you think this is not just the idle session of a connection from your connection pool?

Comment: I was wrong about 'Execution query'.I corrected it.STATUS is INACTIVE. Also, I think that it is illegal that there is a record of V$LOCK of the corresponding session.